# When solving double integral, how do I find the range over where I evaluate the integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus

For example:

(1)Use the change of variables $x=u^2-v^2, y = 2uv$ to evaluate the integral $\int\int_R y dA$, where $R$ is the region bounded by the $x$-axis and the parabolas $y^2 = 4-4x$ and $y^2 = 4+4x$, $y \ge 0$.

(2)Evaluate the integral $\int\int_R e^{(x+y)/(x-y)}dA$ where $R$ is the trapezoidal region with vertices $(1,0),(2,0),(0,-2),(0,-1)$

For these two questions, I couldn't find over what range do I evaluate.

Comment: I can't see what the point of the change of variables is in question 1).  eyeballing it, the region R is symmetric about the x axis, and $\int y dy = 0$  For the second one, consider the change of varaibles, $u = x-y$, $v = x+y.$  tranform those 4 coordines to uv space. (1,1)(2,2),(2,-2),(1,-1).  Find equations for the 4 lines that bound it, and the integration should be straightforward.

Comment: @DougM It's the original question that requires the change of variable

Comment: @DougM  can you be more specific about how to" tranform those 4 coordines to uv space"?

Comment: full answer is below... but if $(x,y) = (1,0)$ and $u = x - y$, and $v = x+y$, then $(u,v) = (1+0, 1-0)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the original problem requires a change in variables. Lets give it a try

$x = u^2 - v^2, y = 2uv$
substitute into the two equations for the parabola

$4u^2v^2 = 4 - 4u^2 + 4v^2\\
4u^2 (1+v^2) = 4 (1+v^2)\\
u^2 = 1$

$4u^2v^2 = 4 - 4u^2 + 4v^2\\
v^2 = 1$

jacobian

$\|(\frac {dx}{du},\frac {dy}{du})\times (\frac {dx}{dv},\frac {dy}{dv})\|\\
\|(2u, 2v)\times (-2v,2u)\|\\
4(u^2 + v^2)$

$\iint  (8uv)(u^2 + v^2) du dv\\
u^4 v^2 + u^2 v^4 |_{-1}^1 |_{-1}^{1}\\
 0$

2)

$u = x-y, v = x+y\\
x = \frac 12(u+v), y = \frac 12(v-u)\\
dy dx = \frac 12 dy dx$

Region is bounded by $u = v, u = -v, u = 1, u = 2$

$\int_1^2\int_{-u}^u \frac 12 e^{v/u} dv du\\
\int_1^2 \frac 1{2u} (e - e^{-1}) du\\
\frac 12 \ln 2  (e - e^{-1}) du$

Answer (score 1):

1. Sketch a picture of the region $R$.
2. For a double integral with $x$ on the outside and $y$ inside, what are the least and greatest values of $x$ for points in $R$?  Given $x$ in this interval, what intervals (hopefully only one) for $y$ produce a point in $R$?
3. If (2) is inconvenient or difficult, try it with $y$ outside and $x$ inside.